# omission of prepositions before time phrase

Tags: prepositions

We often omit prepositions before time phrase. But certain qualifier is included we don't need to use prepositions.
If so, are these two sentences different in meaning.

> Then one summer, she surrendered paying the interest.
>
> Then in one summer, she surrendered paying the interest.

I prefer the first as I think ''one'' is a determiner.

Answer (score 1):

Both are fine.  Using "in" emphasizes that this event happened *during* the summer of one year, but the overall meaning is the same.

Also there would normally be a comma after "then":

> For most of her childhood she was shorter than the other kids.  But **then, one summer,** she grew an inch and a half.
>
> For most of her childhood she was shorter than the other kids.  But **then, *in* one summer,** she grew and inch and a half.