# Omission of a preposition: "and I got me an alibi (for) the night he accuses me"

Tags: prepositions

> A police officer: So, you are telling me that Merrill poisoned your farm because he thinks you poisoned his, which, of course, you didn't.
>
> The one he is talking to:  No, sir, and I got me an alibi the night he accuses me.
>
> (A dialogue from the TV series Stranger Things)

Should I understand it as there is a "for" omitted:
... and I got me an alibi (for) the night he accuses me.
The alibi is for that night？

Comment: Yes. People in relaxed situations, or in rural locations, often don't talk like they do in language text books.

Comment: It's common to omit prepositions (for/on/in) before time phrases especially in casual speech (it's maybe more American than British). See https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/140297/omission-of-prepositions-before-time-phrase https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/93769/missing-preposition-for-before-time

Answer (score -1):

You are correct. He has an alibi (for) that night. The show appears to be using poor grammar (“I got me” rather than “I have”) to portray an unsophisticated character, someone with a country/rural background, or someone of low intelligence.